# Flutter: How to run the geolocator plugin in device background

Tags: flutter

I want to allow the GPS tracking to run on a background. I implemented GPS tracking by using geolocator plugin, but I found that geolocator plugin doesn't support receiving and processing location updates while running in the background. I found some plugins that run the app in the background([flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service), [workmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager), [background_fetch](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch)). I want to know which one can help me to achieve my goal. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Among these options, if your primary goal is continuous GPS tracking in the background, you might find flutter_background_service to be the most suitable choice. It provides more flexibility and control over background execution compared to the other plugins. It provides a simple API for starting and stopping background services. However, you may still explore other options based on your specific requirements and preferences.